# how to use different jabref files for each chapters in latex book

Tags: bibliographies

I want to write a book that contains a reference for each chapter using latex. I am using Jabref for managing the references.

Comment: That seems to be something for the `chapterbib` package. Note that those are bibtex files. Jabref is just a managing software.

Comment: I am preparing a book with 6 chaptres. for each chapter I have jabref file. I want to print 1st jabref for chapter1,  2nd jabref for 2nd chapter,.. like that

Comment: As I'm saying those are bibtex files and you will be getting much more results if you search on bibtex than jabref. The chapterbib package can do what you want.

Comment: I used chapterbib, but it does not work

Comment: DId you read the manual for the chapterbib package? Each chapter has to be in its own file (I think there is a way around this but that is what I normally do). There are then extra `.aux` files that one need to run bibtex on. You have mentioned nothing about your setup, so I don't know your tools. I would assume that since overleaf uses latexmk it would automatically pick up the presence of chapterbib and run bibtex on the extra files.

Comment: Additionally "it does not work" does not really help much. What exactly did you try?

Comment: You can do this also with biblatex. Search about    `\therefsegment` and  `\newrefsegment`.